# For AlwaysOn AGs, can a secondary replica cause contention on the primary when the resources of the secondary are maxed out?

Tags: replication, availability-groups, locking, data-synchronization, blocking

Is it possible and in what ways can the secondary replica cause contention against the primary replica when the secondary replica's resources are maxed out (e.g. does the primary "lock" up while waiting on the secondary to catch up on synchronizing)?

Does it make a difference if the Availability Mode of the secondary replica is set to Asynchronous commit vs Synchronous commit?

Answer (score 2):

In very simple terms:

In **asynchronous mode**, if the replica can't keep up with its primary then the log send queue will just increase indefinitely until the load is reduced.

In perfmon:
*SQLServer:Database Replica Log Send Queue*

Bascially the primary will keep humming along but the replicas will just end up further and further behind.

In **synchronous mode**, if the replica can't catch up, then you will see an increase in transaction delay on the primary. In other words the time the primary spends waiting on replicas to commit / harden a transaction.

In perfmon: 
*SQL Server Database Replica :Transaction Delay*

Unless ofcourse the replica is offline, then there is no delay.

For more detailed reading on what causes latency in synchronous mode: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2018/04/05/troubleshooting-data-movement-latency-between-synchronous-commit-always-on-availability-groups/

@scismon makes a good point. The logs will fill up in async mode if the replica(s) can't keep up.

```
select log_reuse_wait_desc, * from sys.databases
```

log_reuse_wait_desc shows up with AVAILABILITY_REPLICA

Comment: I'd add for async that it could get so far behind that the transaction logs on the primary could fill up since the secondary hasn't hardened them and thus they haven't been backed up clearing the primary.

Comment: Good catch @scsimon, I have added your point to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In synchronous mode, the Primary has to wait for the Secondary to harden the transaction before the transaction can be committed on the primary. Latency, either from hardware or traffic, can cause the log files on the primary to fill which can put additional load on the CPU and disks to clear the log file(s) during a log backup.

[Differences between synch and asynch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-modes-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15)